# Access Script property

Tags: powershell, select-object

I am looking to run a DNS lookup for a local server, select both the hostname and IP address and output to a text file.

```
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry('server1') | 
    Select-Object 'HostName', 'IPAddressToString' |
    Out-File -Path 'c:\temp\DnsIpAddress.txt'
```

I can access `HostName` but cannot select `IPAddressToString`.  I can 
access `IPAddressToString` if I save the results to a variable this way:

```
$result.AddressList.IpAddressToString
```

Can I use `Select-Object` to select `hostname` and `IPAddressToString`?  Or should I do this another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a calculated property with `Select-Object`:

```
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostentry('server1') |
  Select-Object HostName,@{Name = 'IPAddress';Expression={$_.AddressList.IPAddressToString}} |
  Out-File -Path 'C:\temp\DnsIpAddress.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

It may also be worth mentioning that there's a cmdlet `Resolve-DnsName` that may yield more "PowerShelly" code:

```
Resolve-DnsName -name www.stackoverflow.com | Select-Object Name,IPAddress
```